# Why is this div's calculated height more than its content?

Tags: css

I'm a CSS novice working on a WordPress site using the [Menubar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/menubar/) for the navigation.  I've been able to make changes to my CSS for color scheme, centering, and font stuff, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why the div that surrounds the `<ul>` for the menu has an extra 6 pixels at the bottom.  I've tried setting the margin to 0 in several places, changing the `line-height`...but nothing works.

[image]

You can view the site [here](http://classaction.halunenlaw.net).  The theme I'm using is a child of Twenty Eleven.  Here's (I think) the CSS that matters:

```
#access div {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
#access {
    background: #773736; 
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal;
}
#access li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
#access a {
    color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 3.333em;
    padding: 0 1.2125em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

What do I have to do to get rid of this extra height?

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Comment: That site link doesn't work, could you possibly post the offending code in a JSFiddle?

Comment: Did anyone mention that link is broken?

Comment: Is the link an image? Give it a display:block; Also, the link for your site doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry folks!  I'm an idiot.  Link is fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out it was a `line-height` issue:

```
#access {
background: #773736;
clear: both;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 12px;/*this fixes it*/
}
```

Should also point out it was inheriting a line height from body of 1.625 (should be units here)

Answer (score 1):

Stab in the dark...

```
#access a {
   color: #eee;
   display: inline-block;
   line-height: 3.333em; <-- this might be causing it
   padding: 0 1.2125em;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, I encountered a similar issue due to a third-party library setting `line-height: 20px` on the body element, which caused alignment problems for my button.