# HTML div height keeps growing on window resize event

Tags: html, canvas, three.js, element, window-resize

I have simple three.js scene (canvas) which I want to respond upon window resize event (particularly change in the width of the screen, keeping height constant). 
In normal situation i use `window.innerWidth`, `window.innerHeight` property to set the size of canvas to match the window size.

However I want to embed three scene in the html. 
So I have put three canvas in `<div id="three-container">`.

In following code when I resize the window (even width only) the height of the canvas keeps growing. Where is the bug? What am I missing?

To get the size of div container I have tried `container.clientWidth`, `container.offsetWidth` and `$('#three-container').width()` (and height respectively), but for all cases the initial height of div is 0 and keeps growing on resize.

Full code listing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>default</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='three-container' class= "row"></div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.js"></script>
        <script>

            var renderer, scene, camera, cube;
            var time = 0.0;
            var container = window.document.getElementById( 'three-container' );
            var w = 100; //container.clientWidth; // container.offsetWidth
            var h = 100; //container.clientHeight; //  container.offsetHeight

            init();
            loop();

            function init() {

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, w / h, 1, 1000 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.add( camera );

                camera.position.z  = 16;

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor( 0xa696969 );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( w, h );

                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5);
                var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true } );
                cube = new THREE.BoxHelper( new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat ), mat.color );
                scene.add( cube );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', function onWindowResize() {
                    w = container.clientWidth; // container.offsetWidth
                    h = container.clientHeight; // container.offsetHeight

                    console.log( " w : " + w + " h : " + h);
                    renderer.setSize( w, h );
                    camera.aspect = w / h;
                    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                }, false );
            }

            function loop() {
                time += 0.01;
                requestAnimationFrame( loop );
                cube.rotation.x = time ;
                cube.rotation.y = time ;
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where do you set size of the container div in your code?

Comment: @prisoner849 I do not set the size of container.  I only set the size of canvas (through renderer).

Comment: i also have a similar problem when attaching a REGL (a different WebGL library) to my div. when i resize the browser window it grows and grows and grows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`line-height:0;` css-property does the trick and keeps the container's height.

```
#three-container {
  line-height:0;
}
```

The idea to use this property comes from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15664275/why-is-this-divs-calculated-height-more-than-its-content)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/s6shqLzk/) example

Comment: omg thank you for this! This has solved the same frustration I've had for years on the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because the container DIV is actually 104px high initially, even though the CANVAS is 100px high.  I looked in F12 but couldn't see an obvious reason, such as padding.  So you then set the canvas to 104px which makes the div 108px, and so on.

A quick fix is to account for the 4, and this shows you that the above is the problem.

```
renderer.setSize( w, h - 4 );
```

I'm afraid though you will need to find a more robust way to find the difference in height.

Comment: Thanks for hint, on mac the value is 6 not 4, with this fix it indeed keeps the height intact. I have put margin and padding for all items to 0px but still the same result. Looking further for other solution...